# Как на сайте заменить источник на файл из расширения?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Необходимо при установленном расширении брать ресурс локально, а не загружать его из сети.

Разрешения в `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [ "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "contextMenus", "https://example.org/" ]
```

Карта замен:

```
const replaces = new  Map([
    ["https://example.org/file1.avi", "/v1/file1.avi"],
    ["https://example.org/file2.avi", "/v1/file2.avi"],
]);
```

В `onBeforeRequest` :

```
ext.onBeforeRequest = (details) => {
  if(replaces.has(details.url)){
    var replaced_url = chrome.extension.getURL(replaces.get(details.url));
    console.log(replaced_url);
    return {redirectUrl: replaced_url };
  }  
};
```

В консоли расширения выводятся нормальные ссылки.

А на сайте "example.org" - `chrome-extension://invalid/`.

Выходит у сайта, нет доступа к файлам расширения.

Как можно разрешить странице доступ к файлам расширения?

PS: если подставлять ссылки на другой сайт, то при замене заголовка `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` на `*` все работает, но не с фалами расширения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось необходимо явно разрешить доступ к файлам расширения из сети, для этого необходимо в `manifest.json` добавить следующий раздел:

```
"web_accessible_resources":[
    "resources/*",
    "v1/*"
]
```

В примере, все файлы из каталогов `resources` и `v1` будут доступны из сети.